# failed to add hostname and port to remote debugger in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using android emulator for my react-native project.Trying to change the default path(both hostname and server) of remote debugger by adding 'localhost:8081' in dev settings->debug server host & port for device, but it shows following error even tried with running adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081.
[image]

when reload it shows following error
[image]

what is the issue here?

Comment: Try running `react-native start` inside the root project path, and then `react-native run-android`

Comment: what version of react-native are you using? what does the bundler terminal shows upon relead of the app?